# Adding colored outline to text

Tags: text, xamarin.forms

I am newer to xamarin forms and I am currently trying to add an outline to my text here. I am not quite sure how to go about it. I believe it may have something to do with a custom renderer. I have currently attempted to add a background color to the label text but id prefer it to stick more closely to the text.

[image]

Here is my main.xaml

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Grid Padding="40 "/>
        <Label VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Plural Buddy" TextColor="#000000" BackgroundColor="FloralWhite"  FontFamily=" { StaticResource CustomFont3}" FontSize="Large" Padding="0" />
        <Button VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Get Started"  BorderColor= "AntiqueWhite"  FontFamily=" { StaticResource CustomFont3}" /> 
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You will need a custom renderer to access the text UI for each platform - although you might be able to use SkiaSharp.  OR, if this is just a one-off page and not something you are going to do throughout the app, you might be able to pre-draw the text as images instead.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about what pre-draw is?

Comment: draw the text in an image editing tool and then display them as images (or image buttons) in the app

Comment: Yeah okay, that may be a good idea. Let me get back to you on how that progresses. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for pre draw size? Im trying to look and find suggestions but I don't seem to be having success

Comment: you can either draw them as SVG so they scale well at runtime, otherwise you will need to mockup the pages and determine an appropriate size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What effect do you want ? like below ?

[image]

If yes,you could use CustomRederen to achieve it.

**For Android**.

create custom label **OutLineLabel** :

```
public class OutLineLabel :Label
{
}
```

in Android project:

create a custom TextView **StrokeTextView**:

```
class StrokeTextView : TextView
{
    private TextView borderText = null;

    public StrokeTextView (Context context) : base(context)
    {
        borderText = new TextView(context);

        init();
    }
    public StrokeTextView(Context context,IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context,attrs)
    {
        borderText = new TextView(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public StrokeTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs,int defStyle) : base(context, attrs,defStyle)
    {
        borderText = new TextView(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }



    public void init()
    {
        TextPaint tp1 = borderText.Paint;
        tp1.StrokeWidth =5;         // sets the stroke width                        
        tp1.SetStyle(Style.Stroke);                          
        borderText.SetTextColor(Color.White);  // set the stroke color
        borderText.Gravity = Gravity;

    }


    public override ViewGroup.LayoutParams LayoutParameters { get => base.LayoutParameters; set => base.LayoutParameters = value; }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        string tt = borderText.Text;


        if (tt == null || !tt.Equals(this.Text))
        {
            borderText.Text = Text;
            this.PostInvalidate();
        }

        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        borderText.Measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        borderText.Layout(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        borderText.Draw(canvas);
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

create custom renderer **MyOutLineTextView**:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(OutLineLabel), typeof(MyOutLineTextView))]
namespace EntryCa.Droid
{
  class MyOutLineTextView : LabelRenderer
   {
      Context context;
      public MyOutLineTextView(Context context):base(context)
      {
        this.context = context;
      }
      protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
      {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control !=null)
        {
            StrokeTextView strokeTextView = new StrokeTextView(context);
            strokeTextView.Text = e.NewElement.Text;
            strokeTextView.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Purple);
            SetNativeControl(strokeTextView);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

then in page.axml:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black">

    <local:OutLineLabel Text="Hellow World"> 
    </local:OutLineLabel>

</StackLayout>
```