# How can I add border/outline for label text?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to add borders for captions in my application, what's the best way to do it?
I've tried using outline fonts [(examples)](https://www.1001fonts.com/outlined-fonts.html) but they are transparent and I need white text with black border.

Comment: you can use SkiaSharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use custom renderer to achieve this effect.

**For ios**:

create a custom **OutLineLabel** which extends **UILabel** in ios project.

```
public class OutLineLabel:UILabel
{

    public OutLineLabel(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }
    public override void DrawText(CGRect rect)
    {
  
        CGSize shadowOffset = this.ShadowOffset;
        UIColor  textColor = UIColor.White;  //the text color


        CGContext c = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        c.SetLineWidth(2);
        c.SetLineJoin(CGLineJoin.Round);
        c.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Stroke);
        this.TextColor = UIColor.Black;    //the outline border color
        base.DrawText(rect);

        c.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);
        this.TextColor = textColor;
        this.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(0, 0);
        base.DrawText(rect);
        this.ShadowOffset = shadowOffset; 
    }
}
```

create custom renderer **OutLineLabelRenderer** in ios project

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(OutLineLabelRenderer))]
namespace your namespace
{
  class OutLineLabelRenderer:LabelRenderer
  {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        OutLineLabel outLineLabel = new OutLineLabel(Element.Text);
        SetNativeControl(outLineLabel);
    }
  }
}
```

**For android**

You could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61519384/10768653).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you!